# Does "Maximum image resolution" resize before saving on the site?

Tags: media

I am building a site using Drupal 7, in which users can upload content and images.

When I set the "Maximum image resolution" (on the core image field settings) to be, for example -  800x600.

Is that mean that the pictures will first be resized and weight reduced, and only then will be saved on my Drupal site?

I don't want to have many pictures that weight a lot on my server. I prefer to save only the images that has been resized, in order to have more space on my server.

Answer (score 1):

that setting means that you can't upload an image with max resolution of 800x600. If you upload an images with a size more than that set, it will be not imported and drupal will return an error alter.

Comment: That's what I thought, and that's the reason I asked the question. But, when I defined max resolution of 800x600, and max file upload of 10 MB. then I tried to upload image that weigh 6.9 MB with resolution of 3872x2592 - and it works. In addition I got the following message: "The image was resized to fit within the maximum allowed dimensions of 800x600 pixels." when I check - the size of the image in my drupal /public_html/sites/default/files is 83.86 kb.

Comment: are you using the Media module or the standard upload box?

Comment: No. but it's looks like great module.